# Stars & Bars Method With Binary Numbers that Could Be Negative

Tags: combinatorics

AS many of you know, in the "Stars and Bars" method, we wanted to know the # of ways to sum **k POSITIVE numbers** to equal the number **n**, we use the formula C(n-1,k-1).

However, what happens if I place two restrictions:

1) the k numbers we are summing, can only be 2 numbers, binary
2) the values each of the k numbers could possible be is 1 or -1.

What I am trying to do is figure out how many possible ways are there to have k numbers sum to some value where the rolling sum across the k numbers (x_1,x_1,x_2...x_k) can be either be positive or negative.

For example, if k=8, and n=6, we could have (1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1)=(8!/(6!*2!))

Answer (score 0):

Let $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$$ be an equation in which each $x_i$, $1 \leq i \leq k$, is either $1$ or $-1$.  Let $y_i = x_i + 1$.  Then $y_i = 0$ if $x_i = -1$ and $y_j = 2$ if $x_j = 1$.  Then
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = n + k$$ 
is an equation in even non-negative integers.  To see this, observe that if a $m$ $x_i$'s are equal to $1$, the remaining $k - m$ are equal to $-1$, and $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$, then $$n = m \cdot 1 + (k - m)(-1) = m - k + m = 2m - k$$ 
so $2m = n + k$. Thus, 
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = 2m$$
where $m$ is the number of ones that appeared in the original sum.  Let $2z_i = y_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$.  Then
$$z_1 + z_2 + \cdots + z_k = m$$
is an equation in the non-negative integers in which $m$ of the $k$ $z_i$'s are equal to $1$ and the rest are equal to $0$.  The number of solutions of this equation is the number of ways of selecting $m$ of the $k$ numbers in the sum to be $1$, which is $\binom{k}{m}$.